# special character in adding form element to a html page using jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page that requires creation of forms literally like:

```
<form action="/tasks/<%= allTasks.e[0].id %>/delete" method="POST">
        <button class="deleteTask">Delete</button>
</form>
```

But when in a javascript file using jQuery and I do

```
$(function(){
  let myform=String("<form action='/tasks/<%= allTasks.e[0].id%>/delete' method='POST'>
  <button>DELETE</button></form>");
  $('span').each(function(){$(this).append(myform)});
})
```

It will show Cannot POST /tasks/%3C%25=%20allTasks.e[0].id%20%25%253E/delete

The reason is the special characters %,<> got replaced with those numbers. How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason of POST failure is NOT because of the special characters `%`, `<>` got replaced, but because the server side template stuff (`<%= %>`) is not replaced.

You need to replace `<%= allTasks.e[0].id%>` in the `myForm` String to use the real task id. It means your server side technology need to handle JavaScript file content, or the JavaScript code with `<%= allTasks.e[0].id%>` stuff should be moved to HTML template file.

The HTTP POST request should look like:

```
POST /tasks/33989/delete
```

not

```
POST /tasks/<%= allTasks.e[0].id%>/delete
```

BTW, to make the request more RESTful, it is better to use HTTP method `DELETE`.

UPDATE: If javascript file needs to get task id passed from backend, there is a simple way:

1. In HTML template file, make a `<script>` element.
2. In the above script element, store the task id data in the global window object.

   `window.taskId = '<%= allTasks.e[0].id%>';`
3. In this way, when the HTML is assembled in backend, the above code would be converted to:

   `window.taskId = '77878';`
4. When jQuery need to send Ajax request, it can extract the task id from `window` object:

   `let actionURL = '/tasks/' + window.taskId + '/delete';`

Comment: Thanks for your help! But the situation is: as we create a task, it gets placed in the html. The task has an id field (also the PK) in the sql table. The jQuery code is intended to have these forms created automatically with reference to the variable allTasks.e[0].id that was created as a template variable for rendering the html page. If I hard code <%= allTasks.e[0].id%> in the html for a task, it will work. It's just I want to have it automatically. This should be as simple as not having the special characters converted to numbers, but I just don't know how.

Comment: @jl118 I've edited the answer and provide a simple solution.

Comment: Please note variable `allTasks.e[0].id` is used to generate dynamic html content in server side. Once the html content is generated and returned to browser, it's done. If this variable's value changed in server after the html is returned, browser won't be able to know.